# Do Ajax function on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an Ajax call when the document is ready to fill a select field. My Ajax call looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var marke = $('#marke').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '?eID=getBrand',
        data: { marke : marke },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#modellinput').html(result);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('ERROR:'+errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, this will only work on some action (like on click or on change) but not when document is ready. Any solution?

Comment: Is there any error in console?? And why have you put return false at the end of ready function?

Comment: you can put your ajax code in function and call that function in document-ready.

Comment: Your url looks incomplete : url: '?eID=getBrand'. There should be some default action.

Comment: maybe this code is in event listenter on some action? Try put tihs code on sapaate <sctipt> tag

Comment: What are you getting in `result`? It looks fine to me except for `$('#modellinput').html(result);`. That should be `$('#modellinput').val(result);`

Comment: why are returning false, does your marke have any value?

Comment: if you execute it at document ready why not use server side code?

Comment: The url is not incomplete, i am working with a MVC model, i registered this URL and told it which action to do when the URL get's called. The thing is that the code is working without any problem if i don`t put it on $(document).ready

Comment: Which function is executing from `$ajax` call? `success:` or `error:`? What are you getting inside this? I mean if error then `alert('ERROR:'+errorThrown);`

Comment: It's the `success`... well i get simply nothing inside, no html(), no error in console, nothing. When i do the function on click i get the result i want, some select fields with different values.

Comment: What does console.log(result) show?

Comment: yes, you should test `console.log(result)` or/and `alert(result)` inside `success`.  It might be `$('#modellinput')` doesn't load that time.

Comment: The problem was that '#marke' gets the values from PHP after the document is ready. So the ajax call returned with no result. I now solved it by loading the values of 'modellinput'  with PHP on pageload and then on change doing my ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the (document).ready function separated with the function that you want to use, so that you can run the function after the document ready.

```
(function(window, undefined){

    function initYourFunction() {
        var marke = $('#marke').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?eID=getBrand',
            data: { marke : marke },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#modellinput').html(result);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('ERROR:'+errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        initYourFunction();
    });    
})(window);
```

Hope this answers

Comment: Why would that be any different to putting the code directly in the ready handler? It will still be executed before the ready handler returns.

Comment: Just for a better comprehension if the purpose is to run some function on document ready.
From the sample given it looks like a single function because there is return false at the end, so I just put it separately.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `$(window).load(function(){...})` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){...})`:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
        var marke = $('#marke').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: '?eID=getBrand',
            data: { marke : marke },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#modellinput').html(result);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('ERROR:'+errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

`ready` executes when the DOM is ready, but `load`waits until the entire page is ready.